# Multiple Date Fields database design

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I'm designing an Access `.accdb` for project management. The project contract stipulates a number of milestones for each project, with an associated date. The exact number of milestones depends on an "either/or" case of project size, but max of 6

My employer would like to track a `[Forecast]` date, `[Actual]` date and `[Paid]` date for each milestone, meaning a large sized project ends up with 24 dates associated with it, often duplicated (if a project runs to time, all four dates will be identical)

Currently, I have `tblMilestones`, which has a FK linking to `tblProject` and a record for each Milestone, with the 4 associated dates as fields in the record and a field to mark the milestone as complete or current.

I feel like we're collecting, storing and entering a lot of pretty pointless data - especially the `[Forecast]` date, for which we collect data from our project managers (not the most reliable of data anyway). Once the milestone is complete and the `[Actual]` date is entered, the `[Forecast]` date is pretty meaningless

I'd rather have the contract date in one table, entered when a new project is added, a reporting table for the changeable forecast date, set the Actual date when user marks milestone as complete and draw the paid date from transactions records.

Is this a better design approach? The db is small - less than 50 projects, so part of me thinks I'd just be making things more complicated than they need to be, especially in terms of the extra UI required.

Comment: Do you know what the forecast date is to be used for? You may think that it is pointless, but for future analysis it may very well be crucial.

Comment: Thank you! I am concerned that my set up doesn't properly allow for future analysis.The forecast date is the date that the PM thinks the Milestone will be achieved. It's important during the active stage of the milestone: it's good to know how project is running against schedule. It will change with monthly reporting from PMs, so closer to milestone completion,the closer the Forecast date will be to the Actual. My current simple tbl doesn't track changes in the forecast date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a page out of dimensional data warehouse design and store dates in their own table with a DateID:

```
DateID  DateValue
------ ----------
     1 2000-01-01
   ...        ...
  9999 2012-12-31
```

Then turn all your date fields--Forecast, Actual, Paid, etc.--into foreign key references to the date table's DateID field.

To populate the dates table you can go two ways:

1. Use some VBA to generate a large set of dates, say 2005-01-01 to 2100-12-31, and insert them into the dates tables as a one-time operation.
2. Whenever someone types in a new date, check the dates table to see if it already exists, and if not, insert it.

Whichever way you do it, you'll obviously need an index on DateValue.

Taking a step back from the actual question, I'm realising that you're trying to fit two different uses into the same database--regular transactional use (as your project management app) and analytical use (tracking several different dates for your milestones--in other words, the milestone completion date is a Slowly Changing Dimension). You might want to consider splitting up these two uses into a regular transactional database and a data warehouse for analysis, and setting up an ETL process to move the data between them.

This way you can track only a milestone completion date and a payment date in your transactional database and the data warehouse will capture changes to the completion date over time. And allow you to do analysis and forecasting on that without bogging down the performance of the transactional (application) database.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my quandary& I think I understand what you're recommending. Have just googled ETL and it makes sense. I'm realising that my questions always seem to lead to new questions: associating the dates with projects, allowing for user input and then presenting data back to people in forms they understand/want. Still, I'd rather table the data correctly then work the rest out. Thank you again, I'll experiment with this tomorrow.

Comment: just one more question: so i'd have a tblmsmge with numeric pointers to the dates on the date table, and execute something to store any data change to another tbl as my "warehouse"?

Comment: @KDJ - the best questions are the ones that lead to more questions. So to answer your question: yes, you would have DateIDs as foreign keys in your operational tables if you want to go with a hybrid approach to tracking milestone completion dates. If you want to go with a pure data warehouse approach, then you might as well just store the dates themselves in your transactional database (but not projected date, second projected date, actual date, etc.--just the one). Then you would have an ETL process that ran periodically (say, every night) to update your analytical date warehouse with the

Comment: latest changes. It takes a bit of thought and careful design to implement a good analytical DW. But the benefits are tremendous. E.g. you might be able to build an OLAP cube which people can connect to using Excel and do powerful analyses simply by dragging-and-dropping dimensions and facts into PivotTables.

Comment: Sorry, just realised I needed to mark your answer as accepted. You've also introduced me to some new concepts to study up on, so thank you again for taking the time to respond.